# How to perform UMAP dimensionality reduction?

Tags: machine-learning, dimension-reduction

This new method [UMAP](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap) looks to be better than [TSNE](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/), unfortunately it is not available as a dimension reduction method yet:

[image]

Does anyone know if there exists an implementation of it in, or accessible from, *Mathematica*?

Comment: The method seems to be pretty new ([only published on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03426) in this year's February). You don't expect that anybody implents that for you do you? But with version 11.3, you can try to call the Python code  from within Mathematica (see [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/Python.html)).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher That's true, but I'm hoping someone can figure out how to call into the python code in a clean way...

Comment: @user5601 Excuse me for off-topic question, can you explain me why did you choose to use Mathematica for dimension reduction instead of doing it explicitly in python?

Answer (score 9):

Download [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) (Python 3.7) and install in the directory `C:\Anaconda3`.

In Command Prompt:

```
conda create --name umap python=3.7
conda activate umap
conda install numpy
pip install pyzmq umap-learn
```

In Mathematica:

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python", "C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\umap\\python.exe"]
```

```
python = StartExternalSession["Python"]
```

[image]

```
ExternalEvaluate[python, "import umap"]

umap = ExternalFunction[python, "def DimensionReduce(data): return umap.UMAP(random_state=0).fit_transform(data)"]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 10}];

umap@data
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[%]
```

[image]

Comment: I use anaconda already, is it possible to make more efficient for larger datasets?

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"?